# Route Path in React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs

I have below code in my **App.js**.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Head />
        <Menu />
        <div>
          <Route path="/sam/" component={Signin} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I have below code in my `index.html`

```
<a href="/sam" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>
```

I am trying to change route path like below

```
<Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />
```

and index.html code like below

`<a href="/signin" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>`.

I need to click on this `<a href="/signin" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>` link to redirect to `<Route path="/signin" component={Signin} />`.

But it is not working ?  Why ?

Comment: What doesn't work? Is it the Route component?

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. Could you explain it a bit more, and give the errors that you get for example ?

Comment: Thanks @KnowYourElements.`Signin.js` and `App.js` are components.

Comment: @abuabu From what I see in your code. <Route> Component must be within <Router> Component. See this documentation. https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start

Comment: Thanks @KnowYourElements. But why is it working when I use `<Route path="/sam/" component={Signin} />` ?

Comment: Looks like you are using Route without Router parent

Comment: Thanks @Rutul Patel . But why is it working when I use `<Route path="/sam/" component={Signin} />` ?

Comment: @abuabu You need to show some more code. I would suggest creating code sandbox for it

Comment: Thanks @RutulPatel. Actually I don't know which code is responsible for what and it is a large application. That's why I can't create sandbox for it.

Comment: Thanks @TheTisiboth. When I am clicking on `<a href="/signin" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>` I can't see `Signin.js` component output. There is no error in console. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use "useHistory" hook , check this out : https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory

Comment: Thanks @Malek. Why should I need `useHistory` ? `<Route path="/sam/" component={Signin} />` and `<a href="/sam" class="btn btn-primary">Login</a>` is working without `useHistory`.

Comment: i think i missunderstood your issue , well , try this line of codes instead : `<Router basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
    <switch>
      <Route exact path={'/signin'} component={Signin} />
    </switch>
    </Router>`